# packages#Load returns main module does not contain package

Tags: go

I am trying to run `packages.Load` on ./test/example/svc/node-basic-http, but I am getting `main module (mymodule) does not contain package mymodule/test/example/svc/node-basic-http`.

Following is my config for packages:

```
config := &packages.Config{
        //Dir:
        Mode:  packages.LoadAllSyntax,
        Tests: true,
    }
```

I am quite unsure what's happening here, as I am unfamiliar with go modules and its relation to packages and was unable to find anything similar.